# Unity Shader Graph Animations Stop on Editor and Game Windows (when not in focus or playing)

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate, shader-graph

I'm learning shader graphs but my animations stop if I'm not in play mode. Doing anything in the editor/game window causes the animation to play again. Even moving the mouse over the window is enough. But when I stop the animation stops.

[image]

- I'm using Unity 2021.3.19f1 on Linux (PopOs, Ubuntu based).
- I'm using a Time node for the animation
- The problem isn't specific to the portal animation.

(But I guess these are unrelated to the problem)

P.S.: This doesn't happen in play mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't enable *Always Refresh*, try to enable it:
[image: there is where u can enable it]

Comment: Thanks, never thought it would be as easy as this.